# Python : looking to design a software using Tkinter aiming to isolate a portion of picture with the mouse

Tags: python, image, opencv, tkinter

So I tried to design a software with python and Tkinter.
What i wanna do is an interface (i don't care about the looks) that isolate a portion of picture as the clic of the mouse.
Features : square that follow the mouse, 50px², the portion to cut
           effective portion cut
           the window must have the picture displayed

Here's what i managed to do already :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Jan 23 22:25:33 2015

@author: Dogeek
"""

import Tkinter as tk
import cv2

class Frame(tk.Frame):
    """Main window. Class containing every widget used, and inheriting from     tk.Frame"""
    r = 25
    def __init__(self,window, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,window,width=1024,height=768,**kwargs)
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
        #Widgets and vars
        self.imageLoad = "tennis.gif"
        self.image=tk.PhotoImage(file=self.imageLoad)
        tk.Button(self, text ="quit", command=self.Quit).pack(side="bottom")
        self.Canvas=tk.Canvas(self,width=self.image.width(),height=self.image.height(), bg ='white')
        self.Canvas.create_image(self.image.width()/2,self.image.height()/2,anchor=tk.CENTER,image=self.image)
        self.Canvas.bind('<Motion>',self.hover) #<Motion> or <Enter> ???
        self.Canvas.bind('<Button-1>',self.isolate)
        #self.Canvas.focus_set()
        self.Canvas.pack(side='top')

     def hover(self,event):
        """Function designed to make a cursor sized for the rectangle to     isolate"""
        X = event.x
        Y = event.y
        rect=self.Canvas.create_rectangle(X-self.r, Y-self.r, X+self.r,Y+self.r, outline='black')
        #self.Canvas.delete(rect)
        pass

    def isolate(self,event):
        """Function designed to cut a square out of the main picture and store it. The file lines are here to increment the filename so 
    that it doesn't overwrite the previous ones"""
        x=int(event.x)
        y=int(event.y)
        imagecv=cv2.imread(self.imageLoad)
#for some reason, for it to work, I have to         #put the name hardcoded, cant use my var.       #Is it beacause opencv doesnt handle .gif                 #well?
        """f=open("fichier.txt","r")
        line=f.read()
        count=int(line)
        f.close()
        count+=1
        f=open("fichier.txt","w")
        f.write("{}".format(self.count))
        f.close()"""
        RegionOfInterest=imagecv[y-self.r:y+self.r,x-self.r:x+self.r]
        cv2.imwrite("tennis_cut.png", RegionOfInterest)
        pass
    def Quit(self):
        self.quit()
        self.destroy()

window=tk.Tk()
frame=Frame(window)
frame.mainloop()
```

So it doesn't work as i expect it to. I apologize in advance, English isn't my native language, French is. I would really like some help, i'm stuck here, neither do any of the defined functions work, and i'm really desperate. Thanks.

Edit: I managed to make the isolate function work. The hover function doesnt show my square, which I need to know which piece of picture I cut out. I tried not to delete the square after creating it, or to put a delay with the 'after' method, but no luck.

Comment: "So it doesn't work as i expect it to" - what do you mean? Any errors or undesired output?

Answer (score 0):

so i managed to solve the issue there. I didn't know there was a method Canvas.coords() that allowed me to move my square :
final code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Jan 23 22:25:33 2015

@author: Dogeek
"""

import Tkinter as tk
import cv2

class Frame(tk.Frame):
    """Main window. Class containing every widget used, and inheriting from tk.Frame"""
    def __init__(self,window, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,window,width=1024,height=768,**kwargs)
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.r=tk.IntVar()
        self.r.set(50)
        #Creation des widgets
        self.imageLoad = "tennis.gif"
        self.image=tk.PhotoImage(file=self.imageLoad)
        tk.Button(self, text ="quit", command=self.Quit).grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.Canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width =self.image.width(),height=self.image.height(), bg ='white')
        self.Canvas.create_image(self.image.width()/2,self.image.height()/2,anchor=tk.CENTER,image=self.image)
        self.rect=self.Canvas.create_rectangle(25-self.r.get(), 25-self.r.get(), 25+self.r.get(), 25+self.r.get(), outline='black')
        self.Canvas.bind('<Motion>',self.hover) #<Motion> or <Enter> ??
        self.Canvas.bind('<Button-1>',self.isolate)
        #self.Canvas.focus_set()
        self.Canvas.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.spin=tk.Spinbox(self, from_=1,to=500, increment=2, width=10)
        self.spin.config(textvariable=self.r, font="sans 24", justify="center")
        self.spin.grid(row=0,column=1)

    def hover(self,event):
        """Function designed to make a cursor sized for the rectangle to isolate"""
        X = event.x
        Y = event.y
        self.Canvas.coords(self.rect,X-self.r.get()/2, Y-self.r.get()/2, X+self.r.get()/2, Y+self.r.get()/2)
        pass

    def isolate(self,event):
        """Function designed to cut a square out of the main picture and     store it. The file lines are here to increment the filename so 
        that it doesn't overwrite the previous ones"""
        x=int(event.x)
        y=int(event.y)
        imagecv=cv2.imread("tennis.jpg")
        """f=open("fichier.txt","r")
        line=f.read()
        count=int(line)
        f.close()
        count+=1
        f=open("fichier.txt","w")
        f.write("{}".format(self.count))
        f.close()"""
        RegionOfInterest=imagecv[y-self.r.get()/2:y+self.r.get()/2,x-self.r.get()/2:x+self.r.get()/2]
        cv2.imwrite("tennis_cut.png", RegionOfInterest)
        pass
    def Quit(self):
        self.quit()
        self.destroy()

window=tk.Tk()
frame=Frame(window)
frame.mainloop()
```